# return ajax by call back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I known that ajax success function is can't return data,so I had tried by call back function,but it still there getting undefined return.I have done by variable ***responseText*** ,but I'm not want to do by that.So help me with callback function return data!!!

*HTML*

```
<div id="address">
        <table>
        <thead>
        <th>Department</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Address</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
</div>
```

*JS*

> getAddress callback() is return null

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : "header.php",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function (d) {
            var temp = getAddress(callback); 
            console.log(temp)   // undefined
            var data = JSON.parse(temp);
            $.each(data,function(i,d){
                $("#address tbody").append("<tr><td>"+d[i].dept_name+"</td><td>"+d.Name+"</td><td>"+d.Age+"</td><td>"+d.Address+"</td></tr>");
            });         
            }
        });                     
    });    

     function callback(result){
        return result;
     }
    function getAddress(callback){
           $.ajax({
           url: 'address.php',
           async : false,
           dataType : 'json',       
           success: function(result){
            callback(result);
           }
           });          
    }
```

Comment: What is the PHP code returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the callback in a wrong way. The logic working with the value returned by the ajax call should be within the callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "header.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(d) {
      getAddress(function(data) {
        console.log(data) // undefined
        //var data = JSON.parse(temp); not required as you have `dataType: 'json'
        $.each(data, function(i, d) {
          $("#address tbody").append("<tr><td>" + d[i].dept_name + "</td><td>" + d.Name + "</td><td>" + d.Age + "</td><td>" + d.Address + "</td></tr>");
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

In your code, you are calling `getAddress` with the callback, but since the `getAddress` method is not returning anything the value of `temp` will be undefined.